# Angular7 ngFor with JQueryUI Sortable - weird array render behaviour

Tags: jquery, angular, jquery-ui-sortable, ngfor

I am creating animated reorderable list with JQueryUI sortable and Angular 7.
It works well so far, but the problem occurs, when I am trying to add new object after reordering the list.

Template:

```
                        <img class="img-fluid" src="{{sticker[0]}}">
                        <div class="manage-buttons row mx-0">
                            <div class="col-6 p-0">
                                <!--<button class="m-0 p-0 edit btn btn-sm btn-primary">Edit</button>-->
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-6 p-0">
                                <button class="m-0 p-0 delete btn btn-sm btn-danger">Delete</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

I am simply adding new obj like that:

```
    this.stickers.push(['assets/img/cho-choo.jpg']);
```

Without reordering adding works well, the 'choo-choo.jpg' goes at the end of the list.

But after reordering, when I'm trying to add new image, the image goes to the middle of the content of the sortable list (even if the cho-choo is at last index of the array that I am using in the ngFor).

How can i fix that, and make ngFor render my list items as they are in the array?

Answer (score 1):

Don't push an array. Just push the item

```
this.stickers = [];
this.stickers.push('assets/img/cho-choo.jpg');
```

Comment: I've changed it to

    const temp = this.stickers;
    this.stickers = [];
    temp.push('assets/img/cho-choo.jpg');
    this.stickers = temp;
and it's still doesn't work.

Comment: you can't push to `const`. they are read-only values. can't mutate. Push directly to `stickers `

Comment: but i cant clear the stickers, so i make temp array (i've tried to change it to let temp.., but it didn't work aswell'). When i do just         this.stickers.push('assets/img/cho-choo.jpg');
it doesn't work. The item goes still to the middle of the sortable list.

Comment: https://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/BvcKq

this is basically this code, i've just added Angular to it (ngFor) and sticker array in TS. Sorry for not making the whole demo, but jquery doesn't want to work for me on stackblitz.I hope this will be enough.